# MSQL, Query rows passed a certain date of an initial date?

Tags: mysql

How do i extract all rows greater then 7 days of a start date?, I'm trying to use this query in MySQL. Below is my statement.

```
SELECT * from v_polygons a
INNER JOIN tblProjectData z
on z.Project_ID = a.Project_ID
WHERE DATE_ADD(z.FlyDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) > NOW() + INTERVAL rge DAY
```

I have a start date `z.FlyDate`, So i give it +7 days, then i check to see if that date is greater then `NOW()`

is this correct or have i messed it up?

Comment: I don't know this syntax, but it seems you're adding INTERVAL on both sides of the greater-than test?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
WHERE DATE_ADD(DATE(z.FlyDate), INTERVAL 7 DAY) < DATE(NOW());
```

This will ignore the time part. You can remove `DATE` function call if you want to consider the time as well.